# MongoDB locking until result is found

Tags: java, mongodb, chat, morphia

I am using MongoDB and Morphia, my goal is to make a chat.

My idea is to request all the messages that have a bigger sequential number than a specified number.

For example if you request message 0, you will receive all messages, but if you request message 100, you will only receive messages with sequential number greater than 100.

If there is no message found, the requester should be locked until a message appears, by other words, the requester waits for future messages.

My question is, how is that implemented with MongoDB and Morphia? I don't want to query if there is a newer message periodically...

Does MongoDB supports locking until there is a result?

Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tailable cursor for that.  This example is a bit old but should get you most of the way there.  https://github.com/deftlabs/mongodb-examples/tree/master/mongo-java-tailable-cursor-example

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Java / Morphia is the optimal solution for this problem?

Chat and any other realtime applications, are probably better served by Meteor.js and similar frameworks. Specifically, Meteor's oplog tailing would be cleverer for chats — pushing updates to the clients instead of having them pull / poll. Or in the case of tailable cursors you are not limited to capped collections.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ;-), yes capped collection are quite limiting.

BTW if someone couldn't find tailable iterator, maybe you are importing com.google.code.morphia (I had that error).

Comment: Please answer to answers via a comment.